# Why stack get backwards?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, stack, stack-overflow

I was thinking why when I push something into stack esp decrease and don't increase.

I know that this is the way that stack use in a lot of language, but I want to know why they do this and don't do this in upside down.

I search a lot in internet and don't see a good answer.

I was thinking about this when I was learn about stack overflow, and this is look like if stack was create upside down.. Was very hard to do stack overflow

Comment: Why does it have to go any particular direction?

Comment: Mɥɐʇ ᴉs ʍɹouƃ ʍᴉʇɥ ndsᴉpǝ-poʍu¿

Comment: heap grows up stack grows down, gives you some flexibility.  if your stack started low and went high then you are going to hit it with the heap much sooner.

Comment: @old_timer: Depends on the memory implementation.  You could have the stack at lower memory and grow (upwards) towards the heap.  There is no requirement for a heap or a stack.

Comment: absolutely...this question has no answer...it is one common implementation that may make a decreasing stack make sense.